# Permanent data gathering

Tags: c#, .net, database

I have database and mvc application hosted on iis. I periodicaly gather data from internet and save them in sql database. And i calculate statistic and graphs from these data and publish them in mvc application.

Problem is that iis have recycling period about 1 hour -> meaning that my timer(function) which gather data from interenet is stoped whenever there is server restart, recycling or there is no request on the web page.

solutions i have found are:
turn of recycling - i don't own srv can't do that.
windows service - 99% hostings don't allow host ws...

So is there any solution, service, framework, which purpose is to gather data and i can be sure that it will not stop after some inactivity time or server restart? or is my logic completely wrong and i need to gather data diferently? can it be done on hosting which i don't own? can it be done using iis?

Answer (score 1):

> can it be done using iis?

If the IIS in question has app fabric installed, then that supports an [auto start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) feature, which effectively lets you write 'service like' code which will keep running in the background.

Quick overview [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/09/08/death-to-windows-services-long-live-appfabric.aspx)

Comment: what if hosting dont have app fabric?

Comment: the only thing that springs to mind if you can't put anything on the server is to have a heartbeat running on a machine you can control which can call into your MVC app and kick it off if it has died...seems overkill though